# Google Firebase iOS push works in console but not in API

Tags: php, cordova, cordova-plugins, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase/ to receive Google Firebase messages on a ionic based app.

After set certificates, install plugin and setup Firebase account I was able to receive notifications (on both android and ios devices) sended through the Firebase Console.

But when I send through the Firebase API (https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref) only android devices receive the notification. I'm using the following code:

```
$data = Array
(
    [to] => <token>
    [notification] => Array
        (
            [title] => My Title
            [text] => Notification test
            [sound] => default
            [vibrate] => 1
            [badge] => 0
        )

)

$jsonData = json_encode($data);
$ch     = curl_init("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");
$header = array(
  'Content-Type: application/json',
  "Authorization: key=".$gcmApiKey
);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonData);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $result;
```

No errors are returned:

```
{"multicast_id":904572753471539870406,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1477063422322568734%3d5c78243d5c7824"}]}
```

What can be wrong?

Comment: check token to whom you are sending its should be correct device id

Comment: The token is correct. When I use the same token to send message through Firebase Console the notification arrives.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For iOS, try adding in parameter `priority` set to `high` and `content_available` set to `true` in your payload.

See the parameter details [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref).

Comment: Adding priority  = 'high' solves the problem. Thank you!

Comment: I am having same problem. I have set the `priority = 'high'`, still can not get it to work. Could you please tell if there is something else?

Answer (score 0):

```
try this code

function sendGCM($message, $id) {


    $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';

    $fields = array (
            'registration_ids' => array (
                    $id
            ),
            'data' => array (
                    "message" => $message
            )
    );
    $fields = json_encode ( $fields );

    $headers = array (
            'Authorization: key=' . "YOUR_KEY_HERE",
            'Content-Type: application/json'
    );

    $ch = curl_init ();
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields );

    $result = curl_exec ( $ch );
    echo $result;
    curl_close ( $ch );
}

?>
```

also try it in curl terminal

```
curl -X POST --header "Authorization: key=<API_ACCESS_KEY>" --Header "Content-Type: application/json" https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send -d "{\"to\":\"<YOUR_DEVICE_ID_TOKEN>\",\"notification\":{\"body\":\"Yellow\"},\"priority":10}"
```

Comment: Tried 'registration_ids' instead 'to'. Also tried use 'data' instead 'notification'. Tried many combinations. No success.

Comment: try replacing my code with your migh be there a small mistake which can be viewed

Comment: I tried exactly your code, no success. Using your code notification dont arrives on android too.

Answer (score 0):

a little late but with working example,

I'm using the code below for ios and android push, you are missing the `priority` and `content_available` fields

example :

```
$url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
$fields = array(
            'to' => $token,
            'notification' => array('body' => $message , "sound" => "default"),
            'data' => $message,
            "sound"=> "default",
            'priority' => "high" ,
            'content_available' => false
         );
$headers = array(
            'Authorization:key = your-key',
            'Content-Type: application/json'
        );
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```